# Animate the changing of data in a collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uicollectionview

I'd like to animate a change in my UICollectionView. I have the collectionView as an `@IBOutlet`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
```

And the collection view reloads (so I can change the alpha of each cell) like this:

```
var bulkAwardMode = false;

@IBAction func bulkAwardToggleClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    if(bulkAwardMode == false) {
        bulkAwardMode = true
    } else {
        bulkAwardMode = false
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

However as this is not animated, I tried changing the `reloadData()` line to  `self.collectionView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 0))`, however this just causes a crash with the error `attempt to create view animation for nil view`.

I'm clearly doing something wrong, but I'm not quite sure what. I did also try putting the code in a `UIView.animateWithDuration` block, but that also failed.

Comment: So you want to fade in, fade out the data of each cell, then after 1 second, the other data will show?

Comment: In `cellForItemAtIndexPath` I set the alpha based on whether bulk award is on or not, so `reloadData()` updates the alpha - I'd like that change to be animated. Does that make sense? If it helps, I'm then planning on getting the users to select individual cells to then turn a different colour, if bulk award is on.

Comment: @Ben did you figure out how to solve this error? thanks!

Comment: @sridvijay unfortunately not - the solutions below don't really do what I wanted originally. I'm sure they would result in a similar effect if I changed my method, but that doesn't really explain _why_ what I tried wasn't working.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I ended up just switching to a table view. It's weird as I wasn't able to recreate it in a separate new project just to test it out...

Comment: I ran into this same problem. The odd part is that i had it working for hours until I did something else that caused it to break.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
collectionView.performBatchUpdates({ () -> Void in
   // here you can insert ,delete and animate cells
}) { (success) -> Void in    
   //completion block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the UITableViewDelegate

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell,forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
     UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
            cell.alpha = self.bulkAwardMode
        })
}
```

This function is called when you reload Data.

Otherwise, you could get the visible cells :

```
@IBAction func bulkAwardToggleClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    if(bulkAwardMode == false) {
        bulkAwardMode = true
    } else {
        bulkAwardMode = false
    }
    var visibleCells = tableView.visibleCells
    for cell in visibleCells {
          UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
             cell.alpha = self.bulkAwardMode
          })
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a collectionView not a tableView, but I assume there is an equivalent. Thanks Edward - could you explain why reloadItemsAtIndexPaths doesn't work though?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the dispatch_async? ReloadData is already  an asynchrone method.

Comment: Yeah tried that one - I'd really like to understand the problem rather than just patching over it!